# Did Feyman cite Yuri Manin in his paper "Simulating Physics with Computers"?

Tags: programming, quantum-algorithms, history

In Feyman’s paper "Simulating Physics with Computers", did he cite Yuri Manin as the idea of a quantum automaton that used superposition and entanglement was mentioned in his book a year before?

Comment: You could try here: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 8):

Reviewing Feynman's [paper](https://s2.smu.edu/%7Emitch/class/5395/papers/feynman-quantum-1981.pdf) (PDF link), there is no reference to Y. Manin, nor is there a reference to Manin in Feynman's later "[Quantum Mechanical Computers](http://www.quantum-dynamic.eu/doc/feynman85_qmc_optics_letters.pdf)" (also PDF link).  Deutsch's paper from around then "[Quantum theory, the Church-Turing principle and the universal quantum computer](https://www.daviddeutsch.org.uk/wp-content/deutsch85.pdf)" (also PDF) doesn't mention Manin's work either, but does refer to Albert's work on quantum automata.

Manin's book "Computable and Uncomputable" came out in 1980 and was in Russian; maybe Feynman and Deutsch would have been more aware of the antecedents from Manin but for the Iron Curtain.  Shor [points out](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0005003) that Manin preceded Feynman as well, but also appears to accept that this was an independent result of Feynman and Manin, born about by the Iron Curtain more so than any slight on Feynman's part.

From an oral history of [Kitaev](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdFimwal_aQ) for Caltech, Kitaev notes that Manin's work certainly inspired him to study quantum computing - although Kitaev indicates that it was a small paragraph or two in Russian in the above book. It's my understanding that even in the mid-90's after the end of the Cold War, Kitaev only "knew of" Shor's algorithm but didn't have a way to access Shor's preprint (as the arXiv was pretty young then and the Cold War only recently ended), so he had to develop his own solution to quantum factoring and to what we now call the Abelian Stabilizer Problem.

Answer (score 3):

**Marked Community-Wiki**

---

For giggles I had been interested in any English-language translation of the relevant passage about quantum computation in Manin's book *Vychislimoe i Nevychislimoe* ("*Computable and Uncomputable*").  I couldn't find a publicly-available English-language translation thereof$^\dagger$; accordingly, because the book (in Russian) is available online as a .DjVu file, I was able to open it, convert it to .pdf, and OCR the Cyrillic.

Relying on Google's translation tools, we find the following which I have lightly edited and post here for the community.  Indeed, after discussing DNA-RNA transcription and replication on pages 13 and 14, Manin notes the complexity of quantum simulation on beginning on page 15 (I emphasize certain portions that appear to me to be especially prescient):

> Perhaps, to progress in understanding such phenomena [related to DNA copying and transcription], we lack the mathematical theory of quantum automata. Such objects could show us mathematical models of deterministic processes with completely unusual properties. One of the reasons for this is that ***the quantum state space has a much larger capacity than the classical space***: where there are $N$ discrete states in the classical theory, there are $c^N$ Planck cells in the quantum theory that allows their superposition. When classical systems are combined, their numbers of states $N_1$ and $N_2$ are multiplied, and in the quantum version $c^{N_1 N_2}$ is obtained.
>
> These rough calculations show a much greater potential complexity of the quantum system's order of magnitude compared to its classical imitation. In particular, due to the lack of a unique division of the system into elements, ***the state of a quantum automaton can be considered in many ways as a state of completely different virtual classical automata***. (Compare with the following instructive calculation at the end of [17]: "For the quantum mechanical calculation of a methane molecule, it is required to carry out calculations using a grid method at $10^{42}$ points. If we assume that only $10$ elementary operations should be performed at each point, and assume that all calculations are performed at an ultralow temperature ($T=3\cdot 10^{-3} K$), then the calculation of the methane molecule would require using up the energy produced on Earth in about a century.")
>
> The first difficulty in running this program is choosing the right balance between mathematical and physical principles. A quantum automaton must be abstract: its mathematical model must use only the most general quantum principles, without prejudging physical realizations. Then the model of evolution is a ***unitary rotation in a finite-dimensional Hilbert space***, and the model of virtual division into subsystems answers ***the decomposition of the space into a tensor product***. Somewhere in this picture there must be an interaction described traditionally by Hermitian operators and probabilities.

Certainly many portions of Manin's passage line up very nicely with those of Feynman's "nature isn't classical" paper/talk.  How much more would they have progressed together, had they been able to easily communicate?

$^\dagger$ Indeed I missed it when I first wrote this answer but Preskill quotes Victor Albert's translation of the same first paragraph of Manin in Preskill's [Quantum computing 40 years later](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.10522), and also emphasizes the same quote as **"the quantum phase space is much bigger than classical."**

---

<sup>The passage in Russian, as OCR'ed from a .pdf of the .DjVu file:</sup>

> <sup>Возможно, для прогресса в понимании так~1х явлений нам недостает математической теории квантовых автоматов Такие объекты могли бы nоказать нам математические модели детерминированных процессов с совершенно непривычными свойствами. Одна из причин этого в том, что квантовое пространство состоян1tй обладает гораздо большей емкостью, чем класс1tческое: там, где в классике имеется $N$ дискретных состояний, в квантовой теории, допускающей их суперпо·зицию, имеется $c^N$ планковских ячеек. При объединении классических систем их числа состоя·ний $N_1$ и $N_2$ перемножаются, а в квантовом варианте получается $c^{N_1 N_2}$.</sup>
>
> <sup>Эти грубые подсчеты показывают гораздо большую потенциальную сложность квантового по~еден1tя с1tстемы по сравнению с его класси· ческой имитацией. В частности, из-за отсутствия однозначного разделения системы на элементы состояние квантового автомата может рассматриваться многим1i способами как состояние совершенно раз· ных виртуальных классических автоматов. (Ср . со следующим поучительным подсчетом в конце работы [17]: "Для квантовомеханического расчета молекулы метана требуется провести вычисления по методу сеток в $10^{42}$ точках. Если считать, что в каждой точке следует выполнить всего 10 элементарных операций, и предположить, что все вы· числения производятся при сверхнизкой температуре ($T=3\cdot 10^{-3} K$), то и при этом расчет молекулы метана потребует израсходовать энер· rию, производимую на Земле примерно за столетие".)</sup>
>
> <sup>Первая трудность при проведении этод программы состоит в выборе правильного баланса между математическими и физическими принципами. Квантовый автомат должен быть абстрактным: его математическая модель должна использовать лишь самые общие кван· товые принципы, не предрешая физических реализаций. Тогда модель 9волюции , есть унитарное вращение в конечномерном rильбертовом пространстве, а модель виртуального разделения на подсистемы ОТВЕ'· чает разложению пространства в тензорное про изведение. Где-то в этоit картине должно найти место взаимодействие, описываемое по тради· ции эрмитовыми операторами и вероятностями.</sup>